# Create a Smart Folder based on an EXIF keyword?

Tags: finder, photos, smart-folders, exif

How can I create a Finder Smart Folder based on an EXIF keyword?

I confirm that the EXIF keyword exists using exiftool. For example, I added the keyword "Mango" to an image and created the Smart Folder like so:

- Open a Finder window
- New Smart Folder
- Click the Plus icon
- Change Name to Keywords
- Next to Matches I type Mango
- Click Save
- Save it in the default location (~/Library/Saved Searches)
- Click the Mango Smart Folder in my Sidebar but it returns no results

How can I create a Finder Smart Folder that searches the files' EXIF keywords?

Comment: When you create the Smart Folder, are you making sure that the scope of the search is what you want? (e.g. "This Mac" vs. "Documents" etc.)

Comment: Related and possibly a duplicate: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/214041/how-to-write-exiftool-keywords-which-spotlight-can-see

Answer (score 1):

Note this works for .jpg images (not .png).

- Open a Finder window
- New Smart Folder
- Click the Plus icon
- Change Name to Other
- Search Raw
- Click Raw query and OK
- Next to Raw Query type "kMDItemKeywords = Mango"
- Click Save
- Name the saved search and save it in the default location (~/Library/Saved Searches)
- Click the Mango Smart Folder in the Sidebar and see your result

Thanks @patrix